# Рефакторинг кода вывода данных в datagriview

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

Есть вот такая модель базы данных:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
База данных SQL Client, подключен напрямую (не через сервер).

Как в datagridview вывести таблицу Zayavki, чтобы выводились не цифры (они же ключи), а данные из столбца с фамилией, именем и отчеством по первичному ключу. То есть, чтобы таблица заявок выглядела примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(P.S. вывод в datagridview с дальнейшей возможностью добавления записей, удаления и редактирования)
Сама таблица сейчас выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Как в datagridview вывести таблицу Zayavki, чтобы выводились не цифры (они же ключи), а данные из таблиц по первичному ключу* Таблицу? Никак. А вот результат выполнения запроса, включающего как источник данных все эти должным образом связанные таблицы - это да. Читайте, что такое JOIN и с чем его едят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что хотелось-бы отметить - не храните идентификатор в формате int. Используйте для этого Guid. Его можно создавать как на стороне сервера, так и на стороне клиента. Это гораздо безопаснее. Единственное, насколько я помню, не все бд позволяют хранить тип UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, поэтому можно создать nvarchar(36), если такой возможности нет (36 - ограничение длины).

Второе, обработка данных должна происходить в идеале на сервере, а не на клиенте. Погуглите про WCF Service. Можете поискать реализацию чата на ютубе и сделать по аналогии [Пример](https://youtu.be/QohqDyTjclw). Также, можете реализовать на сервере кэш, из которого клиент будет брать данные. Советую использовать для этого [ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-6.0), где Guid - идентификатор объекта, а T - какой-то класс, привязанный к этому Guid.

Третье, для отображения данных в DataGridView (в дальнейшем, dgv) используйте привязку данных. Касаемо данной темы есть тонна статей и ответов на stackoverflow. [Пример создания привязок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1199457/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-datagridview/1199692#1199692)

Четвёртое, при реализации какого-либо приложения старайтесь придерживаться архитектурных паттернов. [Пример реализации MVVM паттерна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412712/c-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-datagridview/1412948#1412948)

[Полезная ссылка про то, как конвертировать DataTable (из select запроса) в List](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1388067/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B2-net-c/1388205#1388205)

Итак, учитывая выше сказанное можно с лёгкостью сказать, как реализовать то, о чём вы говорите в вопросе:

Пример класса Order, в котором будет храниться информация о заказе:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid OrderId { get; private set; }

    public Guid ServiceId { get; private set; }
    
    public Guid UserId { get; private set; }

    public Guid DoctorId { get; private set; }

    public Guid ClientId { get; private set; }

    public Order(Guid orderId, Guid serviceId, Guid userId, Guid doctorId, Guid clientId)
    {
        OrderId = orderId;
        ServiceId = serviceId;
        UserId = userId;
        DoctorId = doctorId;
        ClientId = clientId;
    }
}
```

Таким образом, мы имеем `List<Order>`, из которого нужно получить данные из соответствующих таблиц согласно Guid (у нас так же существуют List, List, List, List, которые мы можем получить согласно ссылкам выше.

Создадим класс, который будет привязываться к dgv:

```
public class OrderInfo : ObservableObject //ObservableObject - информация по ссылке выше
{
    private Guid _orderId;
    private string _serviceName;
    private string _userName;
    private string _doctorFullName;
    private string _clientName;
    private DateTime _createTime;

    [DisplayName("Номер услуги")]
    public Guid OrderId
    {
        get => _orderId;
        private set
        {
            _orderId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OrderId));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Название услуги")]
    public string ServiceName
    {
        get => _serviceName;
        private set
        {
            _serviceName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ServiceName));
        }
    }
    
    [DisplayName("Имя пользователя")]
    public string UserName
    {
        get => _userName;
        private set
        {
            _userName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserName));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("ФИО доктора")]
    public string DoctorFullName
    {
        get => _doctorFullName;
        private set
        {
            _doctorFullName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DoctorFullName));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("ФИО клиента")]
    public string СlientName
    {
        get => _clientName;
        private set
        {
            _clientName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(СlientName));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Дата")]
    public DateTime CreateTime
    {
        get => _createTime;
        private set
        {
            _createTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CreateTime));
        }
    }

    public OrderInfo(Guid orderId, string serviceName, string userName, string doctorFullName, string clientName, DateTime createTime)
    {
        OrderId = orderId;
        ServiceName = serviceName;
        UserName = userName;
        DoctorFullName = doctorFullName;
        ClientName = clientName;
        CreateTime = createTime;
    }
}
```

Итак, класс у нас создан, осталось создать BindingList и заполнить его ([Делаю по аналогии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412712/c-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2-datagridview/1412948#1412948)):

```
internal class Form1ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Order> _orders;
    private readonly IEnumerable<User> _users;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Doctor> _doctors;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Service> _services;
    private readonly IEnumerable<Client> _clients;
    private BindingList<OrderInfo> _orderInfos;

    public BindingList<OrderInfo> OrderInfos
    {
        get => _persons ?? new BindingList<OrderInfo>();
        set
        {
            _persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OrderInfos));
        }
    }

    public Form1ViewModel(IEnumerable<Order> orders, IEnumerable<User> users, IEnumerable<Doctor> doctors, IEnumerable<Service> services, IEnumerable<Client> clients)
    {
        _orders = orders;
        _users = users;
        _doctors = doctors;
        _services = services;
        _clients = clients;
    }

    private void CreateOrderInfos()
    {
        foreach (var order in _orders) //в методах ниже может выпасть исключение, если First не найдёт Guid, поэтому либо добавьте сюда try-catch, либо ваш будет необходимо обезопасить вашу бд
        {
            var user = GetUserById(order.UserId);
            var service = GetServiceById(order.ServiceId);
            var doctor = GetDoctorById(order.DoctorId);
            var client = GetClientById(order.ClientId);
            var orderInfo = new OrderInfo(order.Id, service.Name, user.Name, doctor.FullName, client.Name, order.CreateTime);
            OrderInfos.Add(orderInfo);
        }

        static User GetUserById(Guid userId) =>
            _users.First(x => x.Equals(userId));

        static Service GetServiceById(Guid serviceId) =>
            _services.First(x => x.Equals(serviceId));

        static Doctor GetDoctorById(Guid doctorId) =>
            _doctors.First(x => x.Equals(doctorId));

        static Client GetClientById(Guid clientId) =>
            _client.First(x => x.Equals(clientId));
    }
}
```

Далее, необходимо лишь привязать эти данные к нашему dgv:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1ViewModel _viewModel;

    public Form1(IEnumerable<Order> orders, IEnumerable<User> users, IEnumerable<Doctor> doctors, IEnumerable<Service> services, IEnumerable<Client> clients)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = new Form1ViewModel(orders, users, doctors. services, clients);
        dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(DataGridView.DataSource), _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.OrderInfos));
    }
}
```

Советую прочитать: [Соглашения о написании кода](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions).

P.S. Старички программирования, не пинайте, пожалуйста, меня за конструкторы с 5 параметрами. Я знаю, что такую длинную колбасню лучше собирать в 1 класс, но прописывать ещё и это было-бы слишком объёмно