# c# datagridview перенос значений из одного datagridview в другой datagridview

Tags: c#

пытаюсь сделать Шопинг корзину из datagridivew. выделил товары с помощью Checkbox из одного Грида - в другой копировался выделенные значения. значения переносятся, проблема в том, что при обновлении основного грида выделенные значения во втором гриде - корзине пропадает. как сохранить выделенные значения втором гриде ? Дело в том что основной датагрид фильтруется с помощью Combobox . при каждом фильтраций данные в гриде обновляется

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Qty");
        dt.Columns.Add("Category");
        dt.Columns.Add("Company");
        dt.Columns.Add("Date");  
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            bool isselect = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Check1"].Value);
            if (isselect)
                dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells[1].Value, row.Cells[2].Value, row.Cells[3].Value, row.Cells[4].Value, row.Cells[5].Value, row.Cells[6].Value);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView2.Columns[0].Width = 45;
            dataGridView2.Columns[1].Width = 150;
            dataGridView2.Columns[2].Width = 67;
            dataGridView2.Columns[3].Width = 90;
            dataGridView2.Columns[4].Width = 105;
            dataGridView2.Columns[5].Width = 75;
        }
    }
   public void SelectMetod()  // показать данные
    {
        con.Open();

        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT sklad.id, sklad.name, sklad.amount, category.name, company.name, sklad.date FROM sklad LEFT JOIN company ON sklad.companyID = company.id LEFT JOIN category ON sklad.categoryID = category.id", con);
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dset);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        con.Close();

    }
 DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        checkColumn.Name = "Check1";
        checkColumn.HeaderText = "Select";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, checkColumn);
        checkColumn.Width = 45;  



      private void FilterCategory()  

    {
        string sats = comboBoxCategoryName.Text.ToString();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT sklad.id, sklad.name, sklad.amount, category.name, company.name, sklad.date FROM sklad LEFT JOIN company ON sklad.companyID = company.id LEFT JOIN category ON sklad.categoryID = category.id WHERE category.id = '" + sats + "'", con);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        table.Clear();
        adapter.Fill(table);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
        DVGStyle();
       
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод CreateTable

```
private DataTable table()  // VIEW DATAGRIDVIEW
      {
         using (MySqlConnection connection = ConDatabase.GetDBConnection())
          { 
          MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT sklad.id, sklad.name, sklad.qty, category.name, company.name, sklad.date FROM sklad LEFT JOIN company ON sklad.companyID = company.id LEFT JOIN category ON sklad.categoryID = category.id", connection);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }  

      }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18266539/13123688 Ответ на зарубежной версии форума

Comment: @Frehzy , не совсем понял пример, там про клонирование идет речь ?

Comment: А что вы не поняли? Там в первом же ответе показан пример реализации того, что вы хотите сделать - перемещение выделенной строки из одной таблицы в другую. Показаны привязки к dgv и в ивентах клика прописано перемещение

Comment: @Frehzy, перемещение у меня есть, у меня не получается сделать вот таким образом, где используется BindingSource  [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Vum8uhzLNc&t=1s]

Comment: Что не получается? Какая ошибка появляется? Может исчезнут вопросы, если прочитаете  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1413761/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-datagriview/1413988#1413988

Comment: @Frehzy, спасибо за ссылку, прочитаю,  я явно не так делаю как надо, у меня Datagridview выводит данные из склада что есть, необходимо  сделать корзину покупок. выбирал один товар, перекинул в корзину. вот тут возникает проблема, когда обновляю грид склада выбранный товар со второго грида исчезает

Comment: Добавил ответ. Посмотрите. В случае возникновения вопросов, оставляет комментарии под ответом. Если это помогло вам, поставьте галочку

Comment: @Frehzy, много ошибок выскакивает, можете помочь ?

Comment: @Frehzy, извиняюсь что так долго молчал, пытался разобраться что- к чему, выше выложил код, можете посмотреть , там где Orders.Add как указать свой DataTable ? что сделал не так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, вы сделали запрос (скопировал из вашего кода выше) `"SELECT sklad.id, sklad.name, sklad.amount, category.name, company.name, sklad.date FROM sklad LEFT JOIN company ON sklad.companyID = company.id LEFT JOIN category ON sklad.categoryID = category.id"` и в конечном счёте получили DataTable. Для привязки данных необходимо использовать конкретные классы.

Итак, заходим в гугл и ищем какую-нибудь информацию по запросу "c# datatable to list". [Первая же ссылка](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/different-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list/), но в чём проблема? А в том, что этот код подходит для конкретного запроса, для конкретной таблицы, для конкретного класса. Мы ведь кулл-программисты, которым слишком лень писать один и тот же код, поэтому начинаем гуглить про рефлексию, т.к. именно она может нам помочь в данном вопросе.

Спустя какой-то время мы делаем что-то похожее [на, например, это](https://qawithexperts.com/article/c-/ways-to-convert-datatable-to-list-in-c-with-performance-test/93), либо берём [этот метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1388067/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B2-net-c/1388205#1388205) и чуть правим под свои нужды.

Итак, теперь мы имеем на руках List (где T - какой-то наш класс ([смотреть эту ссылку для понимания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1413761/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-datagriview/1413988#1413988)). Нам нужно создать BindingList (где Y - новый класс, который нужно отображать. Если T - тот класс, который нужно отображать, то новый не обязательно создавать) и вставить в него наш List. Делаем это просто через цикл foreach.

После этого нам необходимо привязать наш BindingList к DGV (информация об этом по ссылке выше).

Теперь у нас всё готово для перемещения. Что такое "перемещение выделенной строки из одной таблицы в другую"? Это получения индекса выделенной строки, удаление из одной (в нашем случае, удаление из BindingList) и добавление в другую (другой BindingList). А так как BindingList наследуется от IBindingList, который наследуется от IList, можно сделать вывод, что методы взаимодействия с List здесь точно такие же.

Получить значение - `IndexOf()` ([Подробнее](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.indexof?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)). Далее, удаляем - `RemoveItem()` ([Подробнее](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.removeitem?view=net-6.0)). Далее, добавляем - для этого можем использовать `Add()` ([Подробнее](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1_Add__0_)) или `AddNew()` ([Подробнее](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.addnew?view=net-6.0)). Скорее всего, вам пригодится простой `Add()`. [Информация про разницу между этими методами](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198052/system-componentmodel-bindinglist-addobject-vs-addnew)

Таким образом, нам осталось лишь получить индекс выделенной строки, по которой мы будем выполнять методы, описанные выше. Гуглим "c# datagridview get selected row index" и получаем в первой же ссылке ответ - `datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex` ([Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578144/index-of-currently-selected-row-in-datagridview))

UPD:

Создаётся впечатление, что вы огромный болт забили на ссылки, которые я кидал вам и пытаетесь скинуть всю свою работу на меня, хотя по факту, делать там почти ничего не нужно. Тем не менее, вот создание привязок:

Создаём Product (Model):

```
internal class Product : ObservableObject
{
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private int _qry;
    private string _category;
    private DateTime _date;

    [DisplayName("Номер услуги")]
    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        private set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Название")]
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        private set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Qry")]
    public int Qry
    {
        get => _qry;
        private set
        {
            _qry = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Qry));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Категория")]
    public string Category
    {
        get => _category;
        private set
        {
            _category = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Category));
        }
    }

    [DisplayName("Дата")]
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => _date;
        private set
        {
            _date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
        }
    }

    public Product() { }

    public Product(int id, string name, int qry, string category, DateTime date)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Qry = qry;
        Category = category;
        Date = date;
    }
}
```

Создаём ObservableObject, которая будет реализовывать INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
internal class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Создаём Form1ViewModel (ViewModel):

```
internal class Form1ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private BindingList<Product> _products;

    public BindingList<Product> Products
    {
        get => _products ?? new BindingList<Product>();
        set
        {
            _products = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Products));
        }
    }

    public Form1ViewModel(IEnumerable<Product> products)
    {
        _products = new BindingList<Product>();
        foreach (var product in products)
            Products.Add(product);
    }
}
```

Корректируем Form1 (View). Метод `CreateTable` замените на ваш SQL запрос, после которого остаётся DataTable. Пояснять тут ничего не буду - это крайне легко и, даже если не знаете, загуглить можно:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Form1ViewModel _viewModel;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var list = CreateTable().ToEnumerable<Product>();
        _viewModel = new Form1ViewModel(list);
        dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(nameof(DataGridView.DataSource), _viewModel, nameof(_viewModel.Products));
    }

    private DataTable CreateTable()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "SomeProduct1");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "SomeProduct2");
        return dt;
    }
}

internal static class Converter
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this DataTable dataTable)
    {
        var objType = typeof(T);
        var properties = objType.GetProperties();

        var list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var row in dataTable.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var instance = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Activator.CreateInstance(objType), typeof(T));
            foreach (var prop in properties)
            { 
                var index = dataTable.Columns.IndexOf(prop.Name);
                if (index < 0)
                    continue;

                var item = row.ItemArray[index];
                prop.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(item, prop.PropertyType));
            }
            list.Add(instance);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Отображается только 2 строки, которые добавил в методе CreateTable.

Перемещение сделаете сами - удаляете из Products и добавляете в корзину, которую нужно будет по аналогии сделать: так же создаёте ещё одну привязку, описываете класс с корзиной (по аналогии с Product, если это нужно). Таким образом, удаляете из `BindingList<Product> Products` и добавляете в (вы его сделаете сами) `BindingList<ShoppingCard> ShoppingCardProducts`

Comment: у меня накопился очень много вопросов, можете помочь разобраться ?

Comment: @jun66 Какие вопросы? Задавайте их. Я ведь написал "В случае возникновения вопросов, оставляйте комментарии под ответом"

Comment: извиняюсь что так долго молчал,  пытался разобраться что- к чему, выше выложил код, можете посмотреть , там где `Orders.Add`   как указать  свой DataTable  ? что сделал не так ?

Comment: Зачем вы дублируете сообщения? Я и под одним увидел-бы. Итак, проблема в том, что вы зачем-то создаёте дважды привязки. 1 раз - `dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", this, nameof(Orders));`, 2 раз - `dataGridView1.DataSource = data;`. Зачем? Вы уже сделали первую привязку (это правильно). Вы даже заполняли данные для этой привязки (`Orders.Add(new Orders...`). Вам нужно вашу DataTable конвертировать в List<T> (в вашем случае, Order), и по аналогии добавить в коллекцию Orders. Ссылку на то, как конвертировать, оставил выше в ответе

Comment: Следующий вопрос - зачем вы создаёте поля? `MySqlConnection con = ConDatabase.GetDBConnection();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("");

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;` Вам нужно MySqlConnection обернуть в using и после этого открывать соединение `con.Open()`. В таком случае, вам не придётся самостоятельно закрывать соединение. Примеры ведь того, как это сделать, я так же оставлял выше. Как вы смотрели?

Comment: я привязку данных впервые вижу, не могли бы объяснить как отображается данные с привязкой ?  как мне отображать данные по SELECT.  `(Orders.Add(new Orders...)` тут я вручную ввожу данные, а как мне отобразить  те данные которые выбирается по SELECT-y ? и второй вопрос, конвертация Datatable в List<T> , метод ConvertUsingForEach  разве не конвертирует в List ?  спасибо за ваш труд !

Comment: @jun66 А в чем проблема поискать информацию, как работает привязка? Да даже на том же самом ютубе. Да и ссылок я скинул столько, что там этот момент объясняется подробно, поэтому не вижу смысла ещё и здесь объяснять это. Далее, вы ведь всё правильно сделали сначала, но потом зачем-то привязали dataTable. На этом этапе вам нужно конвертировать и вставить в Orders, который привязан к dgv, вместо привязки dataTable. Касаемо метода, впервые вижу. Самый надежный способ - использовать рефлексию, о которой я писал выше. Почему вы просто не скопируете и не используете готовый код?

Comment: ,в ютубе смотрел несколько роликов привязку в основном для WPF. поищу еще, может плохо искал, и да, метод конвертаций с помощью foreach пересмотрю.

Comment: @ 
Frehzy,  выложил выше код , посмотрите пожалуйста если не трудно

Comment: @jun66 Написали полную *****. До этого у вас почти всё было готово. Нужно было лишь немного подправить то, что у вас было, а не переписывать непонятно как... Обновил ответ, добавил инфу после UPD. Не думаю, что ещё вопросы появятся, т.к. сделал почти всё за вас. Вам нужно лишь по аналогии немного доделать. Если конечный ответ вас устроил - поставьте галочку.

Comment: @ Frehzy, простите пожалуйста вас зато , что достаю! последняя просьба, выше выложил метод Createtable, можете просто сказать правильно или нет .

Comment: @jun66 https://pastebin.com/5r3T9YVA Подправил

Comment: @ Frehzy,    ` var list = CreateTable().ToEnumerable<Product>();`   тут ругается что, отсутствует аргумент, а в аргументах только  `query`  я в ступоре  ....

Comment: @jun66 https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.9.php

Comment: @ Frehzy,   спасибо за статью прочитал,   `  var list = CreateTable(Name).ToEnumerable<Product>(); `      таким образом заполнил параметр, но  VS выдает такое сообщение                 
       PROCEDURE moysklad.Form3 does not exist"